# printf making new line on space

Tags: bash, shell, printf

I have the following printf code, it puts a newline in everytime it hits a space in my files. How do I stop it adding in this newline.

File list:

```
mytest
mytest stuff
new test things
```

Code:

```
for i in `find / -iname *test*`; do
  printf $i'\n'; done
```

Output:

```
/var/private/mytest
/var/private/mytest
stuff
/var/private/new
test
things
```

I am trying to strip out the space, and put a newline after each file:

```
/var/private/mytest
/var/private/myteststuff
/var/private/newtestthings
```

Comment: The loop is iterating 6 times with values 'mytest', 'mytest', 'stuff', 'new', 'test', 'things'.  The problem is not with `printf` but with the word splitting in the loop condition.

Comment: This is not a canonical solution (for that, use `find ... -print0... | xargs`, but for this case you can just do `find / -iname '*test*' | tr -d ' '`

Comment: that makes sense, strip out the spaces before doing the printf. thanks

Comment: I mean don't do the printf at all.  Skip the loop and just pipe find to `tr`.   If you need to the loop for some other purpose, it is too fragile to do it this way.  Use `find ... -exec` or `find ... print0 ... | xargs` if you need to manipulate the files.

Comment: You're stepping on [BashPitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) entry #1. The problem isn't with `printf`, it's with `for i in $(find ...)`, which is inherently, irreperably broken. (One can make it *less* broken by disabling globbing and setting `IFS` to only contain newlines, but that's still not unbroken, it's just *less* broken).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` here is only being used to implement something you can do in pure `bash` (assuming version 4 or later):

```
shopt -s nocaseglob globstar nullglob
for i in /**/*test*; do
    path=${i%/*}
    base=${i#$path/}
    printf '%s\n' "$path" "${base// /}"
done
```

Comment: Note that this solution will remove spaces in the names of directories, not just in the file names.  For instance, '/dir a/test 1' will be printed as '/dira/test1'.  It's not clear if that is what the OP wanted.  Also, for full compatibility with the 'find' approach, add `nullglob` to the `shopt -s` (in case there are no test files on the system).

Comment: Your first point occurred to me, but I should address that. Thanks for the reminder about `nullglob`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here has nothing at all to do with `printf`, and everything to do with `` for i in `find / -iname *test*` ``.

When you use an unquoted command substitution, its output goes through two steps:

- Field splitting (which breaks the output into multiple words based on the characters in `IFS` -- by default, spaces, tabs and newlines)
- Glob expansion (where each of those words is evaluated as a glob).

This means that if you had a file created with the command `touch 'my * test'`, then `$i` would subsequently expand to `my`; then to each individual file referred to be `*`, and then to `test`.

---

If you want to iterate over results from `find` safely in bash, and generate a whitespace-free version of each name, doing so looks like the following:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' i; do
  printf '%s -> %s\n' "$i" "${i//[[:space:]]/}"
done < <(find / -iname '*test*' -print0)
```

which will emit content like:

```
/var/private/mytest -> /var/private/mytest
/var/private/mytest stuff -> /var/private/myteststuff
/var/private/new test things -> /var/private/newtestthings
```

Comment: your solution is more sophisticated, you have to replace text with test. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls=$(find . -iname '*test*' | sed 's/ //g')
for i in ${ls} 
do
  echo "$i" 
done
```

Test

```
./mytest
./myteststuff
./newtestthings
```

Comment: The `for` loop in `for i in "$ls"` does nothing at all; you could just as easily not have it, and run `ls=$(find . -iname '*test*); printf '%s\n' "$ls"`

Comment: Also, the first argument to printf is a format string; the string you want to print should be the *second* argument.

Comment: Even as amended, your `for` loop still runs only once no many files are found, and still isn't doing anything of any value whatsoever (you get multiple lines of output because the single value of `$i` your one iteration has contains literal newlines). Consider using `set -x` to trace your script's execution, to make this more clear.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: you'r right, i have made some modification.

Comment: Hmm. That *is* what the OP wants to do. The only real objection I have at this point is that if what they actually intend is to *rename* the names with spaces to the names without spaces, then they need to have their script be able to access both the original and intended names simultaneously, so they can't afford to throw away the original name with its spaces.

Comment: Well, one other caveat -- unless you turn off glob expansion, then the shell will expand each value generated by string-splitting `ls` as a glob. This means that, for instance, `my[test]` will be replaced with `myt` if any file matching that name exists.